# Reset internet on Ubuntu server 20.04 LTS

Tags: networking, server, virtualbox, kvm-virtualization

I converted a VirtualBox image (Ubuntu server 20.04 LTS without GUI) to QEMU image (sudo qemu-img convert -f vdi...). It is start and work, but its ethernet network does not. I can not update it etc.
It does not matter, but it was bridged card (in VM) and in QEMU is NAT (yet).

I found a temporary solution:

sudo dhclient -r

sudo dhclient

After it internet work well, till the next boot.
How can I fix the ethernet settings in the OS?
There is a tool what ran during install?

Answer (score -1, accepted):

You have to modify netplan config file. Replace ens3 by the name of the interface .

You have to execute the command `ifconfig` and you will get the interface name  . Then change the interface name.

```
root@server:~# vi /etc/netplan/01-netcfg.yaml
# enable dhcp4 
network:
  version: 2
  renderer: networkd
  ethernets:
    ens3:
      dhcp4: yes
```

then you can do  a `netplan try` to check if there is no syntax error then do a `netplan apply`

Comment: Thank you very mutch, you spare me an install of Ubuntu sever + MySQL.
Let me some additions only for someone read this article.

1. ip address
   ifconfig did not show my 'ens3' adapter, ip adress did it (without ip address and in 'DOWN' state)
2. cd /etc/netplan
3. ls
4. sudo nano  00-installer-config.yaml
5. change 'enp0s3' adapter name in the 4. row to 'ens3'
6. save nano and close it
7. sudo netplan try
8. sudo netplan apply
9. and the internet working again (after boot also)

Answer (score -2):

My `01-network-manager-all.yaml` had only 4 lines, referring to none of the hardware.

I did the following:

1. `sudo nautilus`
2. Go to `/etc/NetworkManager/system-connections`
3. Optional - back up the contained connections to a subdirectory in your home directory
4. Make a note of file permissions, just in case
5. delete all files
6. `sudo /etc/init.d/network-manager restart`

This worked for me. There may be drawbacks, but, it beats having to re-install ubuntu from scratch.